# How to set raddatepicker date with database retrieved date

Tags: c#, asp.net, raddatepicker

I want to set the `RadDatePicker` value to a value retrieved from my database

I have this code

```
DateTime Podate = Convert.ToDateTime(da.GetDataKeyValue("PoDt"));
RadDatePicker.SelectedDate =Podate;
```

but when I run this program the `DatePicker` shows blank value

What should I do? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try likes this ,

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
     RadDatePicker.SelectedDate = 
     DateTime.Parse(da.GetDataKeyValue("PoDt").ToString());
        }
    }
```

If not working by this code , please check with

```
     RadDatePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

If it work with this , you have to check your retrieve data `da.GetDataKeyValue("PoDt")` .
It may be in wrong datetime dataformat !

Comment: it assign the value to RadDatePicker.SelectedDate
but in my browser it display the blank value!!

Comment: thanks man you saved me

Answer (score 1):

only set the DbSelectedDate property on your telerik control as given below your work will be done :

```
      <telerik:RadDatePicker 
           ID="RDtbenddate" runat="server" 
           DateInput-ForeColor="#00CCFF" DateInput-ToolTip="End Date"
           DbSelectedDate='<%# Bind("JobClosingDate") %>' Width="250">
      </telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate = (DateTime) Contact.Birthdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please not If you use `RequiredFieldValidator`

You must add `Display="Dynamic"` to RequiredFieldValidator

Otherwise `date` would not be displayed